# Compare two strings, including duplicate letters?

Tags: python, string, compare, duplicates

I'm trying to write a function that takes two user inputs: a word and a maximum length. The function reads from a text file (opened earlier in the program), looks at all the words that fit within the maximum length given, and returns a list of words from the file that contain all of the letters in the word that the user gave. Here's my code so far:

```
def comparison():
    otherWord = input("Enter word: ")
    otherWord = list(otherWord)
    maxLength = input("What is the maximum length of the words you want: ")
    listOfWords = []
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        letterCount = 0
        if len(line) <= int(maxLength):
            for letter in otherWord:
                if letter in line:
                    letterCount += 1
            if letterCount == len(otherLine):
                listOfWords.append(line)
    return listOfWords
```

This code works, but my problem is that it does not account for duplicate letters in the words read from the file. For example, if I enter "GREEN" as otherWord, then the function returns a list of words containing the letters G, R, E, and N. I would like it to return a list containing words that have 2 E's. I imagine I'll also have to do some tweaking with the letterCount part, as the duplicates would affect that, but I'm more concerned with recognizing duplicates for now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Counter for the `otherWord`, like this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> otherWord = 'GREEN'
>>> otherWord = Counter(otherWord)
>>> otherWord
Counter({'E': 2, 'R': 1, 'N': 1, 'G': 1})
```

And then your check could look like this:

```
if len(line) <= int(maxLength):
    match = True
    for l, c in counter.items():
        if line.count(l) < c:
            match = False
            break
    if match:
        listOfWords.append(line)
```

You can also write this without a `match` variable using Python’s for..else construct:

```
if len(line) <= int(maxLength):
    for l, c in counter.items():
        if line.count(l) < c:
            break
    else:
        listOfWords.append(line)
```

Edit: If you want to have an exact match on character count, check for equality instead, and further check if there are any extra characters (which is the case if the line length is different).

Comment: Thanks for this, it works perfectly! Just curious, is there a way to create a dictionary of the letters and their counts without having to import something from a module like Counter?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I split the word into letters then assigned each letter a count in a dictionary using str.count(). Thanks again.

Comment: One last question actually: why is the for...else construction necessary? After the for statement, I would like to just be able to say "if c <= line.count(l): listOfWords.append(line)" but I run into the same problem as before. Why is this the case?

Comment: You only compare the count of a single character, so you do not check for all the others. That’s why the for..else or the `match = False` thing (which does the same btw., so you can just use that) is necessary. It waits until all comparisons are made and then checks if all comparison succeeded.

Comment: And btw. the collections module is built-in, so there is no reason why you should not use it. Building a dictionary yourself has most likely a worse performance, especially if you call `str.count` for each character once. (Counter is `O(n)` in construction; `str.count` is `O(n)` per call)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that also lets you perform (multi)set operations:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: c = Counter('GREEN')

In [3]: l = Counter('GGGRREEEENN')

In [4]: c & l  # find intersection
Out[4]: Counter({'E': 2, 'R': 1, 'G': 1, 'N': 1})

In [5]: c & l == c  # are all letters in "GREEN" present "GGGRREEEENN"?
Out[5]: True

In [6]: c == l  # Or if you want, test for equality
Out[6]: False
```

So your function could become something like:

```
def word_compare(inputword, wordlist, maxlenght):
    c = Counter(inputword)
    return [word for word in wordlist if maxlenght <= len(word) 
                                      and c & Counter(word) == c]
```